# Change width of a view having equal width with another view

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have four views with equal height and equal width to each other. Now if I want to change a single view's width to 0 in some conditions, then how can I do that with code? There is no fixed width of any views.

Comment: Have you looked at UIStackView? That might do what you want.

Comment: If you don't want to use UIStackView, then try giving the zero frame to the view you want to have 0 width.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Load in your View Controller:

2.) Turn Off Auto Resizing Mask into Constraints

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NibView" owner:self options:nil];

nibView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

3.) Create your constraints

```
NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:nibView
                                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                                 toItem:nil
                                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                                               constant:yourValue];
```

4.) Add your width constraint

```
[self.view addConstraint:widthConstraint];
```